# Python Correct Global Usage

Tags: python, global

my code currently looks like :

```
import modules
class
functions
main code block (if __name__ == "__main__":)
```

Within the whole of the program I want to add a counter.
My thinking was to add

```
global counter
counter = 0
```

and then add to the counter through out the program. The problem is that it doesnt matter where I place the global command when I start adding the counter within the functions it doesn't reconise the variable.

Where is the correct place to put the global command (i.e start of program etc) and what the correct way to achieve this (is it using a global or maybe via the use of a class ?

Many Thanks,

Comment: I think you should read how to use the `global` statement. And then update your posted code. An answerd based on these lines of pseudocode is nearly impossible.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the global command inside *every* function that needs to rebind the global variable.

You don't need to put it inside functions that only read the global, or which mutate the value but don't rebind it. You don't need to put it outside functions.

Integers aren't mutable so you need `global counter` in any function where you update the counter. If you used a mutable object then you wouldn't need to use `global` at all. e.g.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
       self.value = 0
counter = Counter()

def someFunction():
    counter.value += 1
```

or even make `someFunction` a method of the class.

The `global` keyword (and also `nonlocal` on more recent versions of Python) affects the current scope only.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you must have programmed in C or some other language that allow true program globals.

Python doesn't, unfortunately. As two answerers have already suggested, the simplest way to gain access to a shared namespace is to import a module into every other module that needs access to the shared counter.

Whether you use an `itertools.counter` like @Jon_Clements or a simple (module) global integer like @HVNSweeting is largely immaterial. The significant thing is that there is no truly global namespace available to the programmer in Python.

And don't even think of modifying the built-ins!

Comment: I think I got that now, thanks.  But specifically for such a 'variable' are there any issues to be aware of wether choosing to use a function, a module or class to hold the value?

Comment: The module will be imported by everything needing access to the shared values. How you handle it from there is pretty much a matter of taste,  but if you have a lot of configuration values you might want to use the [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) module to create a global configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare each access of the variable as global where you use it, not once for whole program.  Basically like this:

```
# module
globalVar = 0

def someFuncion():
    global globalVar
    globalVar += 1 # will add to global
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a separate module, initialize your counter in there, then import it to where you need it.

myglob.py

```
#myglob.py
myvar = 0
```

main.py

```
#main.py
import myglob

def addvarone():
    myglob.myvar += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    addvarone()
    print myglob.myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a separate module (possibly called counter) and put something like:

```
from itertools import count

_counter = count(1) # assuming += 1

def get(): # or a more suitable name?
    return next(_counter)

# possibly add a 'peek' function?
```

Then use it in other modules than need it...

```
import counter
import others...

def x(a, b, c):
    curcout = counter.get()
    # ...
pass
```